# exclude results found inside anchor text

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to use regex in php to find all the words count excluding the ones located in the anchor text

I start with /\b(count)\b/i but can not get exactly what I need

```
Cycle count Stored as a <a href="poem://plaspoem/POEM?LOC=MAIN&CMD=VIEW&KEY=CYCLE COUNT&REV=A">Cycle count</a> which is a count of records Cycle count`
```

Comment: Try [`preg_match_all('~<a\b[^<]*?>[^<]*</a>(*SKIP)(?!)|\bcount\b~i', $s);`](https://ideone.com/B23wBE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll can use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/count(?!<\/a>)(?!&)/i
```

Matches: Cycle ***count*** Stored as a `<a href="poem://plaspoem/POEM?LOC=MAIN&CMD=VIEW&KEY=CYCLE COUNT&REV=A">Cycle count</a>` which is a ***count*** of records Cycle ***count***

[EXAMPLE](https://regex101.com/r/WAjOtr/1)

For your second request you would just use a negative look ahead to ignore the word followed by a space and 'time':

```
count(?!&)(?!\stime)
```

[EXAMPLE](https://regex101.com/r/WAjOtr/2)

Matches: Cycle ***count*** Stored as a `<a href="poem://plaspoem/POEM?LOC=MAIN&CMD=VIEW&KEY=CYCLE COUNT&REV=A">Cycle count time</a>` which is a ***count*** of records Cycle ***count***

Now, a word of warning: this is pretty fragile if you do not know what word will follow 'count' when used between the brackets.

Comment: This works however 1 more wrinkle it fails in this string `Cycle count Stored as a <a href="poem://plaspoem/POEM?LOC=MAIN&CMD=VIEW&KEY=CYCLE COUNT&REV=A">Cycle count time</a> which is a count of records Cycle count`

Comment: Did you want to experiment with that? Or did you need me to modify my answer?

Comment: I am experimenting but with no luck, if you could modify the answer that would be great. thank you.

Comment: I guess this is my problem, as I do not know what or how many words could follow 'count' (if any) inside the link. the basics of what I need is match all instances of 'count' not inside the anchor text or anchor html regardless of how many words come before or after it in the anchor

Answer (score 0):

NOTE that in case you have a proper, valid HTML code, you may always rely on PHP DOMDocument and XPath. Since the string is not a valid HTML, you may fall back on a regular expression.

> I do not know what or how many words could follow 'count' (if any) inside the link

If you use `count(?!<\/a>)(?!&)` pattern, it will only fail the `count` substring that is *immediately* followed with `</a>` or `&` (note that expression is the same as `count(?!(?:<\/a>|&))`).

To allow any 0+ characters after the word `count` AND to avoid overflowing across the `</a>` tag, you need to use `[^<]*` construct matching 0+ or more characters other than `<` inside the lookahead.

```
'~\bcount\b(?![^<]*</a>)~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ss0rwe/1)

The regex will match all whole words `count` that are not followed with 0+ chars other than `<` and then `</a>`.

Another approach is more appropriate: we match all `a` tags and skip them, and only match whole words `count` inside other text:

```
'~<a\b[^<]*?>[^<]*</a>(*SKIP)(?!)|\bcount\b~'
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/ss0rwe/2)

Here, `<a\b[^<]*?>[^<]*</a>(*SKIP)(?!)` part matches `<a` + 0+ chars other than `<` as few times as possible up to the first `>`, then `[^<]*` matches the anchor text and `</a>` matches the close tag, and this matched text is dropped, and the next match for a whole word `count` is searched for after that anchor tag.

A [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/kyjt4e):

```
$s = 'Cycle count Stored as a <a href="poem://plaspoem/POEM?LOC=MAIN&CMD=VIEW&KEY=CYCLE COUNT&REV=A">Cycle count</a> which is a count of records Cycle count';
echo "Approach 1: " . preg_match_all('~<a\b[^<]*?>[^<]*</a>(*SKIP)(?!)|\bcount\b~', $s) . "\n\nApproach 2: ";
echo preg_match_all('~\bcount\b(?![^<]*</a>)~', $s);
```